# Помогите написать задачку! С++ Написать встроенную функцию

Tags: c++

Написать встроенную функцию для возведения числа в указанный степени. Степень и число передается в качестве параметров в функцию

Comment: Может сами попробуете, а что не понятно спросите ?

Comment: Закрыто за 8 минут... А какой рекорд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запросто!

```
int powr(int x, int n) {
    int p = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int result = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < x; ++j)
            result += p;

        p = result;
        }

    return p;
    }
```

Comment: Прикол оценен :)